# android studio database app. no data gets inserted. dont understand my catlog

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So im trying to make an app that posts data to my server and to view the data base in the app.

I do have some entries in my database so even the view database option should show me a toast with some information, but i don't get my toast.

The catlog is me trying to add data. This is posted below.

I have had some connection issues. but those are resolved. I lack allot of experience in java so all the help is appreciated.

What am i doing wrong here ?

This is most of my code:

```
public class BackgoundTasks extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        Context ctx;

        BackgoundTasks (Context ctx)
        {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       String RegisterURL = "http://10.0.2.2:80freeln/webapp/register.php";

        String method = params[0];
           if (method.equals("register")) {
                String Shipname = params[1];
                String manufacturer = params[2];
                String price = params[3];

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(RegisterURL);
                    HttpURLConnection httpConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    httpConnect.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpConnect.setDoOutput(true);
                    OutputStream OS = httpConnect.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferdWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                    // send info to server
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Sending data ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String data = URLEncoder.encode("Shipname", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Shipname, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                            URLEncoder.encode("manufacturer", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(manufacturer, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                            URLEncoder.encode("price", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(price, "UTF-8");
                    bufferdWriter.write(data);
                    bufferdWriter.flush();
                    bufferdWriter.close();
                    OS.close();

                    InputStream IS = httpConnect.getInputStream();
                    IS.close();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    return "Ship added";


            }else if (method.equals("RequestDB") ) {
               URL url;
               try {
                   url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:80/webapp/login.php");


                   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                           .openConnection();

                   InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                   InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

                   int data = isw.read();
                   while (data != -1) {
                       char current = (char) data;
                       data = isw.read();
                       System.out.print(current);
                       Toast.makeText(ctx, current, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

           }
           return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

          if (result != null)
            Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

and this is my catlog :

```
0-16 21:01:05.214 7136-7142/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 23.267ms
10-16 21:01:05.960 7136-7302/com.example.simon.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                               [ 10-16 21:01:06.016  7136: 7136 D/         ]
                                                                               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xabc83928, tid 7136


                                                                               [ 10-16 21:01:06.018  7136: 7136 W/         ]
                                                                               Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
10-16 21:01:06.666 7136-7302/com.example.simon.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-16 21:01:06.669 7136-7302/com.example.simon.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
10-16 21:01:06.677 7136-7302/com.example.simon.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xab21d620: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
10-16 21:01:06.696 7136-7302/com.example.simon.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xab21d620: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xabb79620)
10-16 21:01:06.816 7136-7302/com.example.simon.myapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xab21d620: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xabb79620)
10-16 21:01:07.203 7136-7142/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.419ms
10-16 21:01:07.484 7136-7136/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
10-16 21:01:07.535 7136-7136/com.example.simon.myapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-16 21:01:08.246 7136-7136/com.example.simon.myapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-16 21:01:08.810 7136-7136/com.example.simon.myapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-16 21:01:22.819 7136-7142/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 85.426ms
10-16 21:01:23.745 7136-7142/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.830ms
10-16 21:01:24.243 7136-7142/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.550ms
10-16 21:01:27.765 7136-7142/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.642ms
10-16 21:01:35.680 7136-7136/com.example.simon.myapplication W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
10-16 21:01:39.939 7136-7142/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 168.810ms
10-16 21:01:39.989 7136-7136/com.example.simon.myapplication W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
10-16 21:01:40.217 7136-7146/com.example.simon.myapplication I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9541(991KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 60% free, 1465KB/3MB, paused 10.235ms total 549.182ms
10-16 21:01:40.245 7136-7146/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 25.713ms
10-16 21:01:40.785 7136-7142/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.561ms
10-16 21:01:43.346 7136-7142/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 65.096ms
10-16 21:26:11.037 7136-7142/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 18.749ms
10-16 21:36:08.508 7136-7142/com.example.simon.myapplication W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.113ms
```

Comment: First of all make sure that your server script works fine and returns expected response. After that try to send request from Android and confirm it's hitting server script. And why did you tag the question with `Android-Studio` tag? It has nothing to do with problem you're facing.

Comment: I would check first if the if statement is actually executed. You can use Android Studio's debug feature, and set a breakpoint on important parts in your code, like the toast.